# Duplicate records appearing in o.a.spark.sql.sources.v2.writer.DataWriter.writeRecord implementation?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

We are currently exploring Apache Spark (with Hadoop) for performing large scale
data transformation (in Java).

We are using the new looking (and experimental) DataSourceV2 interfaces to build our custom
output data files. A component of this is an implementation of the `org.apache.spark.sql.sources.v2.writer.DataWriter`
interface. It all works beautifully, except for one problem:

**The `org.apache.spark.sql.sources.v2.writer.DataWriter.write(record)` method is often (but not always)
called twice for the same input record.**

Here is what I hope is enough code for you to get the gist of what we're doing:

Basically we have many large sets of input data that we land via a Spark application
into Hadoop tables using code that looks something like:

```
  final Dataset<Row> jdbcTableDataset = sparkSession.read()
    .format("jdbc")
    .option("url", sqlServerUrl)
    .option("dbtable", tableName)
    .option("user", jdbcUser)
    .option("password", jdbcPassword)
    .load();

  final DataFrameWriter<Row> dataFrameWriter = jdbcTableDataset.write();
  dataFrameWriter.save(hdfsDestination + "/" + tableName);
```

There's roughly fifty of these tables, for what it is worth. I know that there are no duplicates
in the data because `dataFrameWriter.count()` and `dataFrameWriter.distinct().count()` 
returns the same value.

The transformation process involves performing join operations on these tables and writing 
the result to files in the (shared) file system in a custom format. The resulting rows contain a unique key,
 a `dataGroup` column, a `dataSubGroup` column and about 40 other columns. The selected records are
 ordered by `dataGroup`, `dataSubGroup` and key.

Each output file is distinguished by the `dataGroup` column, which is used to partition the `write` operation:

```
  final Dataset<Row> selectedData = dataSelector.selectData();
  selectedData
    .write()
    .partitionBy("dataGroup")
    .format("au.com.mycompany.myformat.DefaultSource")
    .save("/path/to/shared/directory/");
```

To give you an idea of the scale, the resulting selected data consists of fifty-sixty million
records, unevenly split between roughly 3000 `dataGroup` files. Large, but not enormous.

The `partitionBy("dataGroup")` neatly ensures that each `dataGroup` file is processed by a 
single executor. So far so good.

My datasource implements the new looking (and experimental) DataSourceV2 interface:

```
package au.com.mycompany.myformat;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Optional;

import org.apache.spark.sql.SaveMode;
import org.apache.spark.sql.sources.DataSourceRegister;
import org.apache.spark.sql.sources.v2.DataSourceOptions;
import org.apache.spark.sql.sources.v2.WriteSupport;
import org.apache.spark.sql.sources.v2.writer.DataSourceWriter;
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

public class DefaultSource implements DataSourceRegister, WriteSupport , Serializable {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(DefaultSource.class);

    public DefaultSource() {
        logger.info("created");
    }

    @Override
    public String shortName() {
        logger.info("shortName");
        return "myformat";
    }

    @Override
    public Optional<DataSourceWriter> createWriter(String writeUUID, StructType schema, SaveMode mode, DataSourceOptions options) {
        return Optional.of(new MyFormatSourceWriter(writeUUID, schema, mode, options));
    }

}
```

There's a `DataSourceWriter` implementation:

```
public class MyFormatSourceWriter implements DataSourceWriter, Serializable {

  ...

}
```

and a `DataSourceWriterFactory` implementation:

```
public class MyDataWriterFactory implements DataWriterFactory<InternalRow> {

  ...

}
```

and finally a `DataWriter` implementation. It seems that a `DataWriter` is created and sent to
each executor. Therefore each `DataWriter` will process many of the dataGroups.

Each record has a unique key column.

```
public class MyDataWriter implements DataWriter<InternalRow>, Serializable {

  private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(XcdDataWriter.class);

  ...

  MyDataWriter(File buildDirectory, StructType schema, int partitionId) {
      this.buildDirectory = buildDirectory;
      this.schema = schema;
      this.partitionId = partitionId;
      logger.debug("Created MyDataWriter for partition {}", partitionId);
  }

  private String getFieldByName(InternalRow row, String fieldName) {
      return Optional.ofNullable(row.getUTF8String(schema.fieldIndex(fieldName)))
        .orElse(UTF8String.EMPTY_UTF8)
        .toString();
  }

  /**
   * Rows are written here. Each row has a unique key column as well as a dataGroup
   * column. Right now we are frequently getting called with the same record twice.
   */ 
  @Override
  public void write(InternalRow record) throws IOException {
      String nextDataFileName = getFieldByName(record, "dataGroup") + ".myExt";

      // some non-trivial logic for determining the right output file
      ...

      // write the output record
        outputWriter.append(getFieldByName(row, "key")).append(',')
          .append(getFieldByName(row, "prodDate")).append(',')
          .append(getFieldByName(row, "nation")).append(',')
          .append(getFieldByName(row, "plant")).append(',')
        ...              

  }

  @Override
  public WriterCommitMessage commit() throws IOException {
      ...
      outputWriter.close();
      ...
      logger.debug("Committed partition {} with {} data files for zip file {} for a total of {} zip files",
        partitionId, dataFileCount, dataFileName, dataFileCount);
      return new MyWriterCommitMessage(partitionId, dataFileCount);
  }

  @Override
  public void abort() throws IOException {
      logger.error("Failed to collect data for schema: {}", schema);
      ...
  }

}
```

Right now I'm working around this by keeping track of the last key that was processed and ignoring
duplicates.

Comment: `partitionBy("dataGroup") neatly ensures that each dataGroup file is processed by a single executor` - that doesn't sound right. `partitionBy`, unlike `repartition`, shouldn't shuffle, so multiple executors can see records for the same group. Would it account for the behavior you see? (though it shouldn't make difference when used with JDBC as shown, as it is not distributed anyway).

Comment: Well, it works - I've found that `partitionBy(...)` on a `DataFrameWriter` has a different meaning to `partitionBy` on a Dataset.

Comment: Actually - after looking at this more closely, you seem to be right about the `partitionBy` behaviour. I am seeing the same dataGroup appear across different executors - which is quite a bummer. I don't think it's related to the duplicate record issue though. The so-called duplicates have different hashcode values which is suspicious.